# how to stop jquery ajax request sent via $.get?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

i am making a ajax request using $.get as soon as the user types a character in the input box
i want to abort the previous ajax calls and then make the new one, is there a way?

**edit**

solved!

i just found out that $.get is a shorthand way to $.ajax and hence it returns a XHR and so we can call abort on that variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery abort() ajax request before sending another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312960/jquery-abort-ajax-request-before-sending-another)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use `.abort()` on XMLHttpRequest that `$.get` returns.

```
var req = $.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
            $('.result').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed.');
          });

//Abort request
req.abort()
```

From [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation:

> The $.ajax() function returns the XMLHttpRequest object that it creates. Normally jQuery handles the creation of this object internally, but a custom function for manufacturing one can be specified using the xhr option. The returned object can generally be discarded, but does provide a lower-level interface for observing and manipulating the request. In particular, calling .abort() on the object will halt the request before it completes.

More on `.abort()`: [XMLHttpRequest.abort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort)

There is also jQuery plugin [AjaxQueue](http://plugins.jquery.com/ajaxQueue/) for handling multiple Ajax request made in parallel.