# Hiding/showing elements on input change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on dynamic search.

When I write in the `#search` input, I want to hide the div `#Main` and display the div `#search_list`. And when I delete what i wrote in the search bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the `#search_list` should hide and the `#Main` div should be displayed again.

Right now, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, the div `#search_list` is not hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var str=  $("#search").val();

        if(str == '') {
             $( "#Main" ).show();
             $( "#search_list" ).hide();
        }  else{
            $.get( "{{ url('home?id=') }}"+str, function( data ) {
                $("#Main").hide();
                $( "#search_list" ).show().html( data );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cory had the right idea, the logic is still wrong though. If you notice in your if/else, both blocks of code are hiding the `#Main` div and showing the `#search_list` div.

You just need to swap the `hide` and `show` methods in your if block.

Edit: As blex pointed out, you want to cancel any pending request before requesting a new one. So add a variable, `req`, that will save each request, than before your if/else, abort that req, if it exists.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // the req variable we will use to track if there is already an open request
    var req;
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var str=  $("#search").val();

        // check to make sure a req exists and it hasn't finished
        // we only want there to ever be one request, so we use the same variable for every request
        if (req != null && req.readyState != 4)
            req.abort();

        if(str == '') {
             $( "#Main" ).show();
             $( "#search_list" ).hide();
        }  else{
            req = $.get( "{{ url('home?id=') }}"+str, function( data ) {
                $("#Main").hide();
                $( "#search_list" ).show().html( data );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: On the right track, but not enough. `$.get()` is asynchronous ;-) He also needs to [abort the request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4163992/1913729) if `str == ''`, otherwise, the wrong divs will show again after the results come back from the server

Comment: Just realized the typo. Whoops.

Comment: @blex he isn't making the request if the str is empty though. That is inside the else statement.

Comment: No, but the previous request might still be pending. I'll show you an example in a minute

Comment: yes the problem is the previous request still show :(

Comment: @milbird I have fixed this per blex's comment

Comment: @blex I think I understood your comment, let me know if the updated answer is what you were thinking

Comment: Exactly! (sorry for the delay, I was trying to make a JSFiddle example, but couldn't figure out how to make `$.get` work on there). +1!

Answer (score 0):

i figured out the problem and here is the code that worked for me ,, thanks for who helped me

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var str=  $("#search").val();


        if(str === '') {
             $( "#Main" ).show();
           $("#search_con").hide();
           $("#search_con").hide();



        }  else{
            $("#Main").hide();
            $( "#search_con" ).show()
            $.get( "{{ url('home?id=') }}"+str, function( data ) {

                $( "#search_con" ).html( data );

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I think @Tyler's answer is better. It will cancel useless requests. Also, your solution will cause this if the network is slow: You type "Hello", the results display. You then delete your search bar, and type something again: the "Hello" results will display again for a short time while the new request is pending

Answer (score -1):

On keypress event find the length of val and also bind  change, paste and focus events
Imagine if some one paste some text.