# How to Access XHR Object When Making AJAX Requests with Backbone's Fetch()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, xmlhttprequest, backbone-events, jqxhr

Within a backbone app, I am making a call with [`fetch`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) when a users takes a certain action:

```
 changeDay: function() {
  this.collection.fetch({
    success: function() {
      lr.primaryView.addAllEvents();
    }
  });
 },
 ...
```

Sometimes, a user takes actions that calls this `changeDay` method again before the first request has successfully responded.  In these cases, I want to cancel the previous request.  I am familiar with how to do this with vanilla jQuery (it is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312960/jquery-abort-ajax-request-before-sending-another)) but I am unable to easily use that approach here since the XHR object is hidden behind `fetch`.  How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone.fetch actually returns the jQuery XHR object:

```
 changeDay: function() {
  thisXHR = this.collection.fetch({
    success: function() {
      lr.primaryView.addAllEvents();
    }
  });
 },
 ...
```