# How to stop Ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to stop an ajax call in jquery, which is not working

```
var xhr = null;

xhr = $.ajax({
    url : 'www.example.com?some-large-call',
    success : function(responseText) {
        // some DOM manipulation
    }
});

$("#button").click(function() { xhr.abort() });
```

I referred the below link

http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/09/29/jquery-stop-an-ajax-call/

Comment: Have you checked the console during this process? If so what does it say?

Comment: Always define 'not working'!!! Because i guess it works but not as you expect it. So what do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

this probally has more XHR..

Please see this answer:

[jquery abort() ajax request before sending another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312960/jquery-abort-ajax-request-before-sending-another)

From the link:

every time you do ajax request, add to array:

```
requests.push(
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/test.php',
    data: search_data,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#catalog').html(data);
    }
}));
```

Then, when you want to stop calls.. 
loop through array and abort all calls..

```
 for(var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++)
requests[i].abort();
```

Thanks

Comment: Link answers are discouraged.

Comment: i dont have enuf rep to add comment to anything else :( - i can delete if ok?

Comment: No need to delete, just add a summary to this answer.

Comment: @JFit you should have voted to close question because of duplicate

Comment: Sorry wolff.. not sure how to do this.. I update my comment..

Answer (score 3):

xhr.abort() it will cause the client to stop listening for the event, but  probably it may  not stop the server from processing it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the code you've pasted is the code you're actually using it's no wonder it doesn't work.

As it states on the site it is just pseudo code to illustrate an example. There is no AJAX request there and nothing to stop (at least nothing large enough to be able to stop)